# Does an uncompressable string exist?

Tags: language-agnostic, compression

I was wondering if there is one or more strings that cannot be losslessy compressed. More formally:

Let `String` be a string, `f(var)` a compression function which returns a compressed version of `var`, `g(var)` a decompression function such that `g(f(var)) = var` and `strlen(var)` a function which returns the length of `var`,
is there a valid value for `String` such that `strlen(String) < strlen(f(String))` or `strlen(String) = strlen(f(String))`?

Theoretical answers are welcome, as well as examples in different languages and with different compression algorithms.

Comment: I can't understand those OT close votes.

Comment: It's probably being closed-voted because it's not a programming question...

Comment: Uhmm, maybe this belongs on [cstheory.SE]?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The *[pigeonhole principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle)* tells us that for any given compression function<sup>*</sup>, there must always be at least one input string  that will be expanded.

---

<sub>* i.e. a function that genuinely compresses at least one input string.</sub>

Comment: Such a precise and to the point answer, + 1

Comment: Any bijective function would have the same property as `f(x)=x`...

Comment: @assylias: Which property?

Comment: I meant many, not any. That won't expand any strings.

Comment: @assylias: Oh, I see what you're getting at.  I'll reword my answer to avoid the issue...

Answer (score 2):

I would expect that this string would fit the bill: ""

Comment: Not necessarily; what if this maps to ""?

Comment: @JanDvorak: Ah, true, I missed that the OP was interested in <=, not <.

Comment: I'm in water deeper than my head with this.  Thanks for the clever answer Oli.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and for a simple reason: take for example a function that is garanty to return a losslessy compressed string that will be at least one bit less for any input string.  Is such a function exists, then by reapplying this same function to its previous result over and over again, we are garanty to compress any string at least one bit further successively for each pass and therefore, we are garanty to be able to compress losslessy any string of any length down to a single bit every time.

Obviously, this is false (some initial strings could give such a final result and it's easy to find about them be applying the decompression algorithm to a compressed string of one bit in length but this result cannot be extended to all uncompressed strings) and therefore, such a function cannot exists; which means that for any compression algorithm, there exists at least one uncompressable string.

Comment: You can't use "obviously" when demostrating something. PRovide an example or an explaination.